# GIT: Can I recover the files after moving a new folder to a project and undoing last commit followed by pull?

Tags: git, gitlab

I will explain what I have done, which seems to have destroyed a folder with files I was working on.

I have a git project, which is fine, and I also have a folder (outside this git project, and no part of any git project) where I had some scripts and some files I generated. I wanted to integrate this folder into the git project, so I moved it there to a right location.

I did a git status, and it said that the new folder was untracked, so I did a

```
git add newfolder
```

I then did a `git status`, and it showed hundreds of pickle *.p files which I had moved, but that I didn't want to commit or push these to the server. So I created a new `.gitignore` file to ignore these `.p` files.

I checked `git status` again, but it was too late, and the `.p` files where already there, so this is when I did my first mistake. I thought "I should undo the last commit" (even though I never committed about adding this new folder so far) and I did

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

After this I did a `git status` and it said I was a pull behind (some changes I did yesterday to that git project) so I did `git pull`.

After this, all the files in `newfolder` disappeared. The only thing still around are the folders I had inside (empty) and some hdf5 files I had in the root `.gitignore`.

So my question is, is there any way to recover `newfolder`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recover files that were added to the index but then removed by a git reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782978/recover-files-that-were-added-to-the-index-but-then-removed-by-a-git-reset)

Comment: This old answer can help you see the blobs that Git has saved from an aborted `git add` - the same thing applies to a `git add` that was followed by a `git reset` like you describe here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54237450/3216427

Answer (score 1):

If you never committed these new files anywhere, then unfortunately they may be lost.  Perhaps you have them backed up somewhere.

Just for information, what you should have done to these Pickle `*.p` files is:

```
git reset -- some/path/to/pickle.p
```

This would simply undo the `git add` step which you did to these files.